File flagged as containing malware
I uploaded a zip file to a SharePoint folder. At first the file was fine but after some time (usually the next day) SharePoint would flag the file as containing malware.
Here is an example screenshot:

We have scanned the zip file with antiviruses and no malwares were detected. The zip file contains some dotnet DLL files from our software development team. We have regenerated the files from our build server multiple times and all were finally flagged as containing malware. We are quite sure this is a false positive.
We have been trying to find a way to mark the file as safe or to report the false positive to someone who can do something about it, but so far we found very little information.
Do you know how to mark the file as safe? Or how to report the false positive?

To report a false positive for a file that has been flagged as containing malware in SharePoint, OneDrive, or Microsoft Teams, you can submit the file to Microsoft for analysis. You can use the procedures outlined in the "Submit malware, non-malware, and other suspicious files to Microsoft for analysis" article to report the file. If the file is determined to be clean, corrective action will be taken to prevent it from being detected as malware in the future. Safe Attachments for SharePoint, OneDrive, and Microsoft Teams is enabled by default and provides an additional layer of protection against malware. However, if you believe that a file has been incorrectly identified as malicious, you can submit it for analysis using the procedures outlined in the article.
